# Save object to existing table "Backendless.com"

Tags: javascript, backendless

I am using backendless.com as a BaaS. So, I can not add objects to existing table.
That`s why I am creating table in my .js file:

```
function Contacts(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.age = args.age || "";
    this.name = args.name || "";
    this.title = args.title || "";
}
function sendData () {
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value,
    name = document.getElementById("name").value,
    title = document.getElementById("title").value;

  var requestObject = new Contacts( {
    age: age,
    name: name,
    title: title,
  });

  var savedRequest = Backendless.Persistence.of( Contacts ).save( requestObject );
}
```

This is index.html file:

```
<form onsubmit="sendData()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="age"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="title" id="title"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But what I need is to add objects to tables which I already created in Backendless.com.
I have table called: Contacts
with columns: age, name, title. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you consequently save the objects using `Backendless.Persistence.of( Contacts ).save( obj )` then the table will be created on the first request (if it hasn't been created yet) and after that the objects will be just saved to the same table.